# Apache POI Cell and Row retrieved via CellReference is Null

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl

**UPDATE:** I've decided to change to Apache POI and all seems to be going well except I am unable to retreive the cell yet it can pick up the row.

```
        CellReference ref = new CellReference("personal_business_name");
        Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
        Cell c;
        if (r != null) {
        c = r.getCell(ref.getCol());
        c.setCellValue(buyers.get(transactions.get(transactionNo-1).getBuyerId()-1).getSurname_organization() + ", " + buyers.get(transactions.get(transactionNo-1).getBuyerId()-1).getFirstname());
        }
```

I can confirm that it is not retrieving the row as I have stepped through the program and it will hit the if statement then skip over it.

---

Older post deleted

Comment: What are you expecting the call to `new CellReference("personal_business_name")` return?  Looking the [CellReference Doc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) I think you are missing something here.

Comment: Hi Viktor, my understanding of it is the CellReference constructor will retrieve the location of that named cell via the string provided.

Comment: I had a search on google for possible solutions and I came across this https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/class-use/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html Although All of my attempts to implement it either directly on the Workbook or on each cell doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: Take a look at the doc of `getCellRefParts`.  I think the constructor expects a string that is made up of the same parts as the method returns.  So actually you are expected to know the location of the cell yourself when calling the constructor.  If you want to get a row or column by its "header" then I'm afraid you will have to write your own function for that.

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to get a Cell by it's reference name. If the CellReference constructor can get a cell such as "A4" shouldn't it be able to call a cell by a name that was given to it so it can easily be referenced? At least that's my understanding of it...

Comment: Do you know of any other ways in Apache POI where I can retrieve the cell via the name that I have given it.

Comment: No I don't think POI has something like that.  But you could always make a `Map` that contains a mapping from names to cell references.

Comment: Thanks Viktor for your assistance with my issue, I found that I needed to include the Name interface (See my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit more googling on the issue this morning and I  came across what has been staring me in the face all the time...

Basically I needed to use the [Name](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.html) interface

```
        Name name = template.getName("personal_business_name");
        AreaReference aref = new AreaReference(name.getRefersToFormula());
        CellReference ref = aref.getFirstCell();
        Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
        Cell c;
        if (r != null) {
        c = r.getCell(ref.getCol());
        c.setCellValue(buyers.get(transactions.get(transactionNo-1).getBuyerId()-1).getSurname_organization() + ", " + buyers.get(transactions.get(transactionNo-1).getBuyerId()-1).getFirstname());
        }
```